# I have this error with game Analytics in Unity : Warn Event queue: Failed to send events to collector - Retrying next time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameanalytics

[image: console log]

I went step by step by document in Game Analytic unity but getting this error

I checked Secret ID and Game key and test on different phones but still have it. Should I Add permission for HTTP or something? I'm using Android.

Comment: What do you think "warn" means?